# Feature selection with L1 Logistic regression, shall I keep negative coefficients?

Tags: logistic, classification, feature-selection, lasso

I am running an L1 LG for feature selection. I have 800 features, I scaled the features, and I would like to know which features should I keep:

```
lr_l1 = LogisticRegression(C = LR_penalty.C, class_weight='balanced',penalty='l1', random_state=42, solver='liblinear').fit(X_train, y_train)
importance = lr_l1.coef_[0]
```

If I consider to keep the features which have an ABS value of the coefficient >1e-5 (*np.abs(importance)>=1e-5*), the result is:

[image]

My question is: is this correct? In other words, should I remove only the features where the coef_ is close to zero or also those with a negative coef_ (*importance)>=1e-5*)?

My final goal is to have good recall and F1 score, since I need to minimise False Negatives.

Comment: If your goal is good F1 core, cross validate both approaches.  No need to remove negative coefficients.  If they are large in absolute value (assuming all the features have been standardized) then they are important.

Comment: What makes you want to remove the features with large negative coefficients?

Comment: @Dave I read it in post, and that drove me to doubting my approach which was to keep negative coefficients.

Comment: In which post did you read that?

Comment: If you don't like negative coefficients, then negate all the explanatory variables that have negative coefficients and re-run the Lasso ;-).